# How to customize a website content to present in a scroll view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a perfect example for what i'm trying to do:

There is a new app called watchville, its an app for watch lovers, and they present rss from several websites in a nice customized way.

This is the page without customization :

[image]

This is the page after you click on the button for the customized view :

[image]

I did the cover image and all, but I want to customize the actual content...header, body etc and make it look elegant like here..

This is what i did:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help?

Tnxxx

Comment: You can modify it on the server end, or you can execute some JavaScript to modify the style sheet, or you can run the site through an API that does this for you like Readability.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the reply, I added two screen shots of what I already did. could you tell me based on that what do you think will be the best way to go? @AaronBrager

Comment: I don't think you want to actually customize the content. I think what you mean is that you just want to extract the content and display what you need within your view. Your just going to have to parse the entire RSS feed xml and feed it to a custom view... The parsing it going to be tricky to get the exact content you want based on how its formatted but its doable.

Comment: @jsetting32 thanks allot, I thought that might be the direction. do you have a source for me that you think can guide me how to parse the rss xml?

Comment: You could check out NSXMLParser to learn lower level XML parsing but I decided to go with Hpple for my project, but thats kinda mid level... If your XML feed is VERY well formatted, this higher level parser will do the trick, XMLDictionary. I doubt you need source code from me, you can do it! I believe in you! But if you get stuck using Hpple, just make a comment. And XMLDictionary is super simple to use

Comment: can I use jason? @jsetting32

Comment: Since RSS feeds are typically formatted in xml, you cannot. Unless the site your getting all this data from has an api that Gives responses back in json. But RSS feeds are basically a well formatted website in xml to extract information from... At least that's what my understanding about it is

Answer (score 0):

Try using paginated web page and you can cache data for pages using NSURLProtocol.

It would load pages and cache onto disk so navigation backward would be from cached and only 1 page would be in memory which is being viewed.

That is best you can do with UIWebView OR you may go for MKWebView it can allow you additional features like javascript.